# Apache will not start on mac osx after installing package php70-ssh2

Tags: macos, apache, php-7

After running

```
brew install php70-ssh2
```

the apache server on my machine will not start.  When I run

```
apachectl -T
```

I see the output

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 170 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): image not found
```

Has anyone else encountered this error and does anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal, if you type `sudo find /usr -name libphp*` you should see a path different from what is in Apache's config file at line 170. Comment out the path in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf at line 170 and paste in the path returned from find command. If the find command doesn't return anything or returns a file different from libphp7.so this would require more info and more troubleshooting.

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no result from this command.  I believe I intalled php70 with homebrew if that helps.

Comment: The underlying cause is that Apache is looking for libphp7.so using the path /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so and not finding it there. On my Mac, the php library file is located at /usr/libexec/apache2/. If you know where to find this file on your machine, use it for the LoadModule php7_module setting in httpd.conf or create a link to that file in the path Apache is configured to find it at or even copy the file into that directory.